# Как в PHP удалить все элементы, которые не входят в число?

Tags: php, массивы, методы, численные-методы

Вопрос не совсем понятен и его трудно сформулировать, поэтому напишу здесь. Есть массив `[12, 34, 42, 18, 12, 86];` и число сколько элементов максимум должно быть в массиве. Например это число 3, то есть массив станет такой - `[12, 34, 42];`. Есть вариант impode, explode с лимитом и array_pop.

Comment: `array_slice($a, 0, 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить срез (он же slice) массива определенной длины (в данном случае - **3**) можно с помощью [array_slice](https://www.php.net/array_slice):

```
print_r(array_slice([12, 34, 42, 18, 12, 86], 0, 3));
```